# The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have two query results, $query1 and $query2

The content of $query1 is printed as follows:

```
{"name":"Gerencia Regional Llanos","name":"Lorem ipsum"}
```

And the $query2 is:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Lorem upsum"},{"id":2,"name":"Lorem upsum"}]
```

When I print $query1 in blade everything is okey, but when I try to print $query2 the server throws the following error:

```
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

In blade I call both of them in the same way:

```
{{ $query1 }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of your first query is a string. But the contents of your second query is converted to an array - I'm guessing because it's a collection of things rather than a single thing. Hence you can't print it with `{{ $x }}`, because that calls `htmlentities()`, which only wants to work with strings.

You can either make sure to just get a single object that can be cast to a string in your second query as well, or you can use a foreach loop to print each item in the collection/array at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the example to solve the problem.
There is require to response the requested data in the mentioned format.

```
 $datas = DB::table('user_table')
                    ->get();
  // response the desired data
   return response()->json(['datas' => $datas], 200);
```

Comment: This helped for me, $ getSections = DB :: table ..... | // The Desired response data | The code in this answer.

Answer (score -2):

**Create the following function**

```
function utf8_encode_deep(&$input) {
    if (is_string($input)) {
        $input = utf8_encode($input);
    } else if (is_array($input)) {
        foreach ($input as &$value) {
            self::utf8_encode_deep($value);
        }

        unset($value);
    } else if (is_object($input)) {
        $vars = array_keys(get_object_vars($input));

        foreach ($vars as $var) {
            self::utf8_encode_deep($input->$var);
        }
    }
}
```

**Try to do the following**

```
utf8_encode_deep($query);
```